# WSO2 API Manager user authencation email

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have setup a WSO2 API Manager. When I create a user in WSO2 using web console/ using admin services, I want to send a user activation email with link to the user.

Can someone point me to documentation OR steps to do this?

I am using MySQL to store my users.

EDIT: I am using WSO2 API Manager version 2

EDIT: When I try to access 
https://:9443/services/UserInformationRecoveryService?wsdl WSDL is not found. 
What are steps to install UserInformationRecoveryService in WSO2 API Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UserInfoRecoveryService](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation) for this requirement.  You may need to install Account and credential management feature. You can [refer](http://chamaleedesilva.blogspot.com/2015/10/enabling-user-password-recovery-for.html) [this](http://chamaleedesilva.blogspot.com/2015/10/enabling-user-password-recovery-for.html) blog to understand how to install that featurs

Thanks
Isura

Comment: I tried installing UserInfoRecoveryService but it is failing to install


Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Account Recovery and Credential Management Feature 4.2.2 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.feature.group 4.2.2) Software currently installed: Identity Core Feature 5.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.feature.group 5.2.0)

It looks like it is trying to install core identity version 4.2.2