# How to send account confirmation e-mail after self sign up on WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

We managed to lock the user store account after self registering an account in the store, but the only way we figured it out to unlock the account is using the admin console (CARBON). We've been trying to make the confirmation e-mail work after self sign up, but we had no luck until now. How could we achieve that?

We are using the WSO2 API Manager 2.5.0. Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I am also stopped in this point.
I only see how to configure this on WSO2 Identity Server, [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation).
But how can I do the same in WSO2 API Manager?
I guess using workflows, or maybe through platform configuration, but it is not explained anywere.

Same question is asked also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828554/wso2-api-manager-user-authencation-email)

It is reported as bug [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/2265)

Could someone bring light this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the use of user signup workflow in APIM [1]. As explains in [2], you can send an email when a user sign up request comes or when a user sign up request completes.

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+a+User+Signup+Workflow
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Customizing+a+Workflow+Extension