# How to send confirmation email to user after register on WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an instalation of WSO2 API Manager, and I would like it sends a confirmation email to new users once they have signed up (registered) on API Store, in order to confirm the email address is valid.

I have seen this is a frequent question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308357/how-to-send-account-confirmation-e-mail-after-self-sign-up-on-wso2-api-manager/), [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/2265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828554/wso2-api-manager-user-authencation-email)), but no answer until now.